# Mobile resizing for rails kaminari pagination with bootstrap theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, pagination, kaminari

I am using kaminari to paginate the index pages of some of my models, and it works quite well. I'm using it with the bootstrap4 theme, and while it looks great, it does not resize well on mobile devices. More specifically, I mean that these links don't resize at all (or if they do, it's minimal), and they extend well beyond the screen to the right, which is annoying. I've tried putting these links inside a bootstrap container, but that didn't cause them to properly resize.

How do I resize kaminari pagination for mobile devices?

Here is the relevant view code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>All Leagues</h1>
    <hr />
    <% @leagues.each do |league| %>
      <p><%= link_to league.name, league %></p>
    <% end %>
    <hr />
    <div class="container">
        <%= paginate @leagues %>
        <%= page_entries_info @leagues %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding this into your  section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

if this doesn't help then try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <h1>All Leagues</h1>
            <hr />
            <% @leagues.each do |league| %>
              <p><%= link_to league.name, league %></p>
            <% end %>
            <hr />
                <%= paginate @leagues %>
                <%= page_entries_info @leagues %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick, it still doesn't resize. I already had that line in the head section of application.html.erb - I tried additionally adding it in this specific view, but that didn't work

Comment: That seems like it should work, but for some reason I'm still getting the same behavior - I should note though that I haven't yet pushed your suggestion to production, so it's possible it will work on an actual mobile device, and is just some weird thing on chrome's development tools